# Not able to connect to postgresql-10 server through terminal (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have an interesting situation over here. I have two versions of postgresql installed on my ubuntu(14.04) machine. I had already installed v9.3 a few days back. When I fire the command `sudo service postgresql start/stop/restart/status` it gives me the status for the version 9.3 while the command `sudo service postgresql-10 start/stop/restart` points me to version 10. I have made necessary changes in the conf and pg_hba files such that v9.3 is running on port 5432 and v10 is running on 5434. Now, when I try and connect to the db server by following commands

```
 psql -Upostgres
 psql -Upostgres -p5432
 psql -Upostgres -Hlocalhost -p5432 
 ...
```

I get connected to the v9.3 server successfully and can see all the databases/tables etc that I have created there.

But when I try to connect to the v10 server, I get the following error:

```
   could not connect to server: No such file or directory
   Is the server running locally and accepting
   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5434"?
```

But the interesting part comes here:

When I run pgAdmin4 server and try and establish connection to the servers, I am able to connect to both the servers, viz, v9.3 and v10.

You can see that in the following image: PostgreSQL 10 is the server that the pgAdmin automatically detected. It also has all the tables that I created yesterday. But somehow, today, I am not able to connect to the v10 running on port 5434. I tried to stop the server running on 5432 and then connect but its not able to connect to the server. Magically, pgAdmin can connect to both that servers that are simultaneously running. The `localserver` is the one with v9.3

[image]

1. How should I debug this issue? What might be happening?
2. Why do we get this error. I am not able to understand that.
3. Yesterday, when I downloaded the postgres, It was able to connect through terminal as well as pgAdmin4.
4. But today, somehow, when I booted into my system it is not able to connect.
5. And more importantly, pgAdmin4 is somehow magically able to connect to both the servers. 
   6.Please help me understand this issue and guide me to debug it. I hope that this will help me understand more on the postgres works as well as how ubuntu handles its services etc. I would be a great exercise for me as I will be able to learn a few things.

Comment: Apparently you can't connect using Unix domain sockets on your installation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+Is+the+server+running+locally+and+accepting) for many questions regarding that). But `-H` selects HTML output, it does not specify the host for a TCP connection. You need to use  `-h ...` (small letter) to do that

Comment: Also make sure to pass the proper port. As of now you try to connect to 5432 which is the standard postgres port. Above you mentioned that version 10 is running at 5434. So use ```-p5434```.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu, run `pg_lsclusters` to display your PG instances and their statuses.